# How do I connect a QTableWidget and a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I have a ***QTableWidget*** where I gathers informations of each item, the information is used in a function called 
**void DrawGraph (QTableWidgetItem *)**
My problem is that I want to create a **QPushButton** that whenever I clicked it calls the function : **void DrawGraph (QTableWidgetItem *)***, but I can't use it because the *Signal* and the *Slot* of *connect* dont have the same entry, I am waiting your help.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to do this way. Read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html or make your `QTableWidgetItem` a private variable and just fire the function `DrawGraph()` in a slot `onButtonCLicked()`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve.  When the QPushButton is clicked which QTableWidgetItem should be passed as a parameter to DrawGraph?  Please show the code you have so far or provide more detail.

Comment: QTableWidget is filled with information recover multiple files, DrawGraph () draws a graph for each selecting item, so I want that every time I click on a button as if I click on an item, after in DrawGraph ( ) I'll make modofications to pass each time in the following item, sorry for my english, I'm not very good in English.